# GWT compilation fails in eclipse

Tags: gwt

GWT compilation fails in eclipse saying the following reason. This used to happen sometimes. Eclipse project clean would solve the issue. But now it doesn seem to work. Any actual issues that might be present? Thanks.

```
Compiling module com.kivar.lumina.Application
       Validating units:
          Ignored 9 units with compilation errors in first pass.
    Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/F:/dev/insanity/agni/client/src/main/java/com/kivar/lumina/shared/requestfactory/requestcontext/SearchRequestContext.java'
          [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.kivar.lumina.server.filter.FilterConfiguration cannot be resolved
          [ERROR] Line 17: FilterConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type
       Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.kivar.lumina.shared.requestfactory.ApplicationRequestFactory'
          Rebinding com.kivar.lumina.shared.requestfactory.ApplicationRequestFactory
             Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryGenerator'/>
                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/F:/dev/insanity/agni/client/src/main/java/com/kivar/lumina/shared/requestfactory/requestcontext/CampaignRequestContext.java'
                   [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.kivar.lumina.server.campaign.CampaignsServiceImpl cannot be resolved
                   [ERROR] Line 18: CampaignsServiceImpl cannot be resolved to a type
                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/F:/dev/insanity/agni/client/src/main/java/com/kivar/lumina/shared/requestfactory/requestcontext/SearchRequestContext.java'
                   [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.kivar.lumina.server.filter.FilterConfiguration cannot be resolved
                   [ERROR] Line 17: FilterConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type
                [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.kivar.lumina.shared.requestfactory.ApplicationRequestFactory'
                   [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
                   [ERROR] Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client';.....
```

Comment: Could you please post your RequestFactory configuration? Should be named ApplicationRequestFactory.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it is visibly seen that there is something wrong with the import with specifically below :

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/F:/dev/insanity/agni/client/src/main/java/com/kivar/lumina/shared/requestfactory/requestcontext/SearchRequestContext.java'
          [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.kivar.lumina.server.filter.FilterConfiguration cannot be resolved
```

Please either add the jar if you want to use FilterConfiguration. Or else, **choose the src folder of the project >> Right Click >> Go to Source >> Click on unorganized imports.**

It will remove all the imports which are not required for project.

Answer (score 0):

From the log I can't say for sure but I can guess that in your RequestContext definitions you are declaring the service implementation. You should declare the service interface instead.

**EDIT:**
If a member of the [Steering Committee](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/steering.html) says my answer is not clear it is probably true.
Apologies and I'll try to be more explicit.
From the log looks like there is some server class (i.e. a class that is executed on the application server; given that the log shows an error from the RequestFactory I presume we are in the middle of some client-server communication here) which is declared in the RequestFactory definition file: *ApplicationRequestFactory.java*.
In particular, I would expect that some parameter in some method of the interface SearchRequestContext is of type FilterConfiguration. This is wrong, you should use the relative proxy instead.
Moreover, looks like in the annotation for SearchRequestContext something like this has been declared:

```
@Service(value=CampaignsServiceImpl.class"...
interface SearchRequestContext extends RequestContext{
...
```

This is also wrong because instead of using the service implementation (i.e. CampaignsServiceImpl) you have to use an interface that is implemented by CampaingsServiceImpl (i.e. the service interface) and that exposes the methods defined in SearchRequestContext, obviously with the necessary translation for the request factory receivers.
This implementation details you can find in the request factory documentation available [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#locators): look up for the paragraph RequestFactory interface.

I hope this all makes sense to you. Please feel free to get back with questions. In case please post your RequestFactory definition file (i.e. the java interface that extends RequestFactory)

Comment: The person who downvoted would be so kind to explain why the downvote?

Comment: What does "service interface" mean here? (vs. "service implementation") and how does it relate to the error?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer is it better now?

Comment: You don't "have to use an interface that is implemented by CampaignsServiceImpl", quite the contrary I would say (though using interfaces for services will also work). The doc about locators doesn't talk about interfaces, only about static vs. instance methods. The "some parameter in some method of the interface SearchRequestContext is of type FilterConfiguration" seems true, but wouldn't explain the issue with `CampaignServiceImpl`.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer hold on, I am not giving lessons here, I am trying to help. If a class is called CampaignServiceIMPL I can imagine that there is a CampaignService interface. In any case, to me CampaignService does not sound a name for a DAO class with static methods to locate the entity. Mine is just a hunch, but sometimes I am right. It would be nice if LPD could post the requestfactrory file and CampaignServiceImpl. Otherwise, what else could be wrong here?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to offense you in any way. With the information given by the OP, I have no idea what's going wrong (which is why I didn't answer), even though I suspect a classpath issue more than a coding issue. My last comment was only meant to correct a few things in your answer: you don't **have to** use an interface; and whether the OP has a `CampaignService` interface or not for the `CampaignServiceImpl` shouldn't change anything to the issue he's facing.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer fair enough, I see your point. Downvote deserved. Actually thanks for pointing that out because I was convinced I always needed an interface in the service annotation of RF.